# Tessellation-like animation in after effects

Tags: after-effects

I am trying to make something I've seen on the local new in the after effects. Now, let's say there's a large picture that has text on it "WBC" or something like that and those letters, when zoomed in are made of smaller pictures. I made the large image in Photoshop and it's pretty decent looking but I can't seem to figure out a way to create this tessellation animation that is probably simple since it revolves mainly around zooming in and moving around but I am a novice in After Effects so i need your help. Thanks ;)

Comment: would you mind adding in some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to sync the scaling and make a cross dissolve between them as you do the scaling.  You want it to fade fairly quickly as you work your way in.  One layer would be the many images in whatever arrangement you want, the other would be the overall logo.  This is also often the technique used for doing a smooth zoom in on a satellite image from a very high level to a lower level.

If you time the fades right, it isn't that noticeable as you move to progressively more detailed images because the more detailed image is starting in while it is still small enough to not be distinguishable.

To keep the sizes manageable, you may also have to do multiple images to transition through.  Don't bring one in to the timeline until the previous image is big enough that details of it will start being noticeable.  Also, be sure to remove the larger previous image from the timeline once the newer image completely covers it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Form or Particular plugins made by Trapcode.  It's the quickest and easiest way to do it.  Make a comp with one image per frame consisting of all the small images.  Make sure the comp size is small - maybe 100x100 or an appropriate aspect ratio compared to your images.

In your main comp, make a text object with the text you want in large white letters.  Hide it.

Create a solid layer.  Apply Trapcode Form to it.  In the Quick Layer styles, for particle opacity, choose your hidden text layer in the XY direction.

This is from memory, so may be a little hazy... Check the Form tutorials like this one:
http://www.redgiant.com/videos/getting-started/item/76/